# Constexpr implicitly declared functions

Tags: constructor, c++14, constexpr, assignment-operator, c++17

For a class of type T, the following members can be generated by the compiler, depending on the class:

- default constructor: `T::T()`
- copy constructor: `T::T(const T&)`
- move constructor: `T::T(T&&)`
- copy assignment operator: `T& T::operator=(const T&)`
- move assignment operator: `T& T::operator=(T&&)`

In C++14, and in C++17, what are the rules that lead to the generation of `constexpr` versions of these functions by the compiler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rule is simple: if the generated definition satisfies the requirements of a `constexpr` function, then it *will be* a `constexpr` function. For example, from C++17, [class.ctor]/7:

> If that user-written default constructor would satisfy the requirements of a constexpr constructor (10.1.5), the implicitly-defined default constructor is `constexpr`.

The wording around implicit default constructors is describes in terms of what a "user-written default constructor" would look like. So "that user-written default constructor" means "what the compiler generates".

Similar wording exists for the copy/move constructors.

The wording is slightly more complex for the assignment operators, but it boils down to the same thing. The type must be a literal type and the assignment operators selected to do the copy/move for each subobject (non-static data member and base class) must be `constexpr`.